# Is it possible to successfully get results when running PsExec in MS Access using Shell.Exec()?

Tags: shell, ms-access, vba, psexec

I'm trying to get the disk status of few servers using PSEXEC for the command in shell and append it to the table. But I only get the caption from the shell result.

here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const svrUname = "username"
Const svrPass = "password"
Const ForReading = 1

Sub First()
    Dim svr(2, 1) As String

    svr(0, 0) = ""
    svr(0, 1) = "server name"
    svr(1, 0) = "PSEXEC \\(IPADD) -u " & svrUname & " -p " & svrPass " 
    svr(1, 1) = ""

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 1
        Call ShellRun(svr(i, 0) & "WMIC logicaldisk get size, caption, " _ 
        & "freespace", svr(i, 1))

    Next

End Sub
Public Sub ShellRun(sCmd As String, svrName As String)
        '  Run a shell command, returning the output as a string
        Dim oShell As Object
        Dim oExec As Object
        Dim oOutput As Object
        Dim a As String

        ' Run command
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
        Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

        ' handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
        Dim sInfo As String
        Dim sLine As String

        While Not oOutput.AtEndofStream
            sLine = oOutput.Readline
        Call EXTRACTINFO(sLine, svrName) 
        a = a & sLine
SKIP:
    Wend
    MsgBox a
    oExec.Terminate

End Sub
```

and the result is only like this　[image: and the result is only like this]

I was hoping to get these results when run from MS access
[image]

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. I guess you miss `Option Explicit` in your module since a variable like `svrUname` exists.

Comment: I have it declared after the Options. My code have Option Compare Database and Option Explicit.

Comment: Without using PSEXEC, "WMIC logicaldisk get caption, size, freespace", it displays completely and acess can read the complete result.

Comment: Still, it cannot compile. And `sCmd` is declared twice.

Comment: Same result. I deleted the duplicate declaration of sCmd. I updated the my post

Answer (score 1):

If I run this code:

```vb
Sub First()

    Const svrUname = "username"
    Const svrPass = "password"
    Const ForReading = 1

    Dim svr(2, 1) As String

    svr(0, 0) = ""
    svr(0, 1) = "server name"
    svr(1, 0) = "PSEXEC \\(IPADD) -u " & svrUname & " -p " & svrPass
    svr(1, 1) = ""

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 0
        Call ShellRun(svr(i, 0) & "WMIC logicaldisk get size, caption, " _
        & "freespace", svr(i, 1))
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub ShellRun(sCmd As String, svrName As String)

    '  Run a shell command, returning the output as a string
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Dim a As String

    ' Run command
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    ' handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
    Dim sInfo As String
    Dim sLine As String

    While Not oOutput.AtEndofStream
        sLine = oOutput.Readline
        'Call EXTRACTINFO(sLine, svrName)
        a = a & sLine
SKIP:
    Wend
    MsgBox a
    oExec.Terminate

End Sub
```

it returns:

[image]

So double-check your EXTRACTINFO function.

**Command file:**

```
C:\Folder\PsExec \\server -u user -p password WMIC logicaldisk get size, caption, freespace > C:\SomeFolder\DiskSize.txt
```

Then read this file.

Comment: it's because the loop you set is For i=0 to 0 and svr(0, 0) = "". You did not used the PSEXEC which is in svr(1, 0). The result you got was from the pc you're using, not from a remote pc..

Comment: Can't tell. I don't have PSEXEC on my Windows 10 machines.

Comment: My question is about using PSEXEC within MS Access. And EXTRACTINFO sub function has nothing to do with the result of the msgbox displayed above

Comment: I don't think you can do that, as psexec opens a new process, so your output will be that of psexec, not that of WMIC. But you can run a command script and write the result to a file - see edited answer.